# Polymer 2; paper-tabs not visible

Tags: polymer-2.x

I'm trying to build a basic toolbar with Polymer 2.0 RC using app-toolbars and paper-tabs. I created the header according to the documentation and added paper-tabs for the bottom app-toolbar, but they're not visible.

- I imported all elements correctly
- I tried to set the height of the second app-toolbar to 100%
- I tried to just use paper-tabs in the main document, but they don't show either
- It does not work in either chrome or FF

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

*my code:*

```
<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
  <!-- app-headers -->
  <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>
    <app-header slot="header" fixed shadow condenses effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar id="topbar">
        <paper-icon-button icon="app-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>WASC Hosting</div>
        <paper-icon-button icon="app-icons:code"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="app-icons:search"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-progress value="10" indeterminate bottom-item></paper-progress>
      </app-toolbar>
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-tabs selected="0">
          <paper-tab>Food</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>Food</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>Food</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <!-- view contents -->
    <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="view-404" role="main">
      <wasc-view-main name="main" class="content"></wasc-view-main>
      <wasc-view-console name="console" class="content"></wasc-view-console>
      <wasc-view-products name="products" class="content"></wasc-view-products>
    </iron-pages>

  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Polymer 2.0 installation Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20).

Have you installed paper-tabs with bower correctly?

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-tabs#2.0-preview
```

Look at my bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#2.0-preview",
    "app-route": "PolymerElements/app-route#2.0-preview",
    "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#2.0-preview",
    "iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon#2.0-preview",
    "iron-media-query": "PolymerElements/iron-media-query#2.0-preview",
    "iron-pages": "PolymerElements/iron-pages#2.0-preview",
    "iron-selector": "PolymerElements/iron-selector#2.0-preview",
    "paper-icon-button": "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button#2.0-preview",
    "paper-tabs": "PolymerElements/paper-tabs#2.0-preview"
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0-rc.4"
},
"resolutions": {
    "polymer": "^2.0.0-rc.1"
},
```